# Django: search on first letters of individual words within phrase?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've got a Django model called `Author`, with a field called `name`, which isn't split up into lastname/firstname:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

For example, I have an Author entry with name 'Donald Knuth'.

Now I'd like to query by name, using istartswith *at the start of each word within the `name` field*.

So I'd like to be able to query with '`Kn`', and get '`Donald Knuth`' back.

Something like:

```
authors = Author.objects.filter(name__word__istartswith="Kn")
```

Is this possible in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`iregex`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iregex) lookup:

```
import re

text = "Kn"
text = re.escape(text) # make sure there are not regex specials
authors = Author.objects.filter(name__iregex=r"(^|\s)%s" % text)
```

This isn't very efficient, but should work. On MySQL you can try taking advantage of [full-text search features](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#search). On other DBs you'll need some extra tools to make an efficient full-text search (like [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/)).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need, except that "(^|\s)%s" only matches at the start of the name. Any idea how I can make it match the start of any word within the name? I'm guessing "\b" should be involved somewhere...

Comment: So "(^| )%s" works, but "(^|\b)%s" and "(^|\b)%s" don't. Curious.

Comment: What's a "\b"? "\s" is a POSIX character group for spaces. What DB are you using ? Try using the alternate syntax: r"(^|[[:space:]])%s" % text

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, [[:<:]] matches the beginning of the word.

```
searchStr = "Kn"
authors = Author.objects.filter(name__iregex=r"[[:<:]]{0}".format(searchStr))
```