# Django istartswith to match separate words within phrase

Tags: regex, django

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390607/django-search-on-first-letters-of-individual-words-within-phrase) is exactly what I am looking for. But I wasn't able to achieve the goal using the info provided in the answer.

I'll illustrate my goal by an example.
For example, I have three strings:

```
John Smith
Lee, John
Micheal Bolton
```

I am looking for a Django filter that would select first(`John Smith`) and second(`Lee, John`) strings, and exclude (filter out) the last one if the user inputs the phrase `John` in the search field.
My code now looks like this:

```
text = "John"
qs = qs.filter(name__iregex = r"(^|\s)%s" % text)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not `qs.filter(name__icontains=text)` ?

Comment: Well, because if the user inserts `ohn`, and don't want to see neither "John Smith" nor "Lee, John. I want only results that START WITH the search text

Comment: I just tested locally this regex and works really nice. What are the edge cases?

Comment: If I type `Smi`, it doesn't render `John Smith`. Moreover, it does include `Esmiralda`, although it shouldn't. Really strange.

Comment: Hmm.. That's strange. I'm using postgres and works brilliantly. `Esmeralda` is not included in the results.

Comment: My stack uses MySQL. Might it be the reason ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139027/discussion-between-edgar-navasardyan-and-nik-m).

Comment: `"^(?=.*%s)" % text` if django supports assertions.